# node.js - download files and content from DB to client

Tags: node.js

I want to send to the client in the same request files from the dir and some content from the DB.

DB query -
`const derivatives = await Derivative.findAll();`

Here is the `res` -

```
res.status(200).send({
      data: derivatives.map((derivative) => ({
        id: derivative.id,
        date: derivative.date,
      })),
    });
```

Here is the download -

```
const fileName = derivatives.map((name) => name.wex);

res.status(200).download(__dirname, `/assets/${fileName}`);
```

How can I add that to my response?

Comment: In what format does your client expect to receive this combination of JSON and file?

Comment: @Quentin The data will be displayed. and the file is for downloading

Comment: No. I asked what format the client expected the data to be sent to it in, not what the client would do with it afterwards.

Comment: @Quentin sorry, I dont get your question

Comment: @Quentin Object. If I got your question right....

Comment: The server sends a message to the client. The client then reads the message. In your first code example, the message is JSON. In your second code example, the message is a file. You want to somehow combine a file and some JSON into a single message. What does that combination of file and JSON look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240152/discussion-between-brgbegnefneg-and-quentin).

Comment: Let's not, because the answer should be a fundamental part of the question, needs editing into it, and if you still don't understand then I don't have the time to continue trying to explain the concept.

Comment: @Quentin ok, ty anyway.
I would be happy if you can explain how can I send JSON and file from dir by file name in the same request.
I dont get what you mean by look like

Answer (score 0):

HTTP lets you specify a "content disposition" to indicate whether a response should be treated as a download, but doesn't support sending downloads arbitrarily, it has to be a response to a request. You can't have part of a response be a download and part be not, for a single request.

So if you need a file to be downloaded, and some JSON used to display some UI, you need to handle that in the client somehow. Either:

- The client sends a request, and server returns JSON containing a URL for the download as well as the other data you wanted to send, and then the client requests a download of the URL through JavaScript
- The client sends two requests, one for the download and one for the other data; this may complicate things on the server if you need to associate the two requests (want to do a database lookup only once for instance), but is simplest on the client.
- The client sends a request, and the server returns a response containing the JSON data and the file data, packed in some way (the file data could be inside the JSON but that would be inefficient), and it's unpacked on the client (using JavaScript) and the client then constructs a Blob URL to "download" (in this case the data is already downloaded, so this just entails saving a file)

There are any number of ways you might pack the file and JSON data together, which is what /u/Quentin was alluding to. Sending both as one response may be better for performance, but you probably don't need to.